# deinit/reinit tinyMCE on dynamically generated DOM

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, dynamic, tinymce

I have an SPA that dynamically loads routes via AJAX and generates the DOM from the output.  Once it's rendered, `tinymce` is initialized into the appropriate element(s).

The problem is that this `tinymce` only initializes on the actual page load.

**How I do I get `tinymce` it to reinitialize when the DOM is dynamically reloaded?**

I've tried using `mceRemoveEditor` and `mceAddEditor` on the appropriate triggers, but it has no effect and reports no errors.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION:**

Unload `tinymce` on any initialized elements *before* unloading current DOM containing the `tinymce` elements.

```
if (typeof tinymce != 'undefined' && tinymce != null) {
        tinymce.remove([selector]);
}
```

Then you can run `tinymce.init()` after loading a new route and generating new DOM elements.